# no android SDK found

Tags: android

I have installed the android studio 3.0.1

During installation, I met this window.

I already set the system variable. (JAVA_HOME -> JDK)

What's the problem?
[image]

Comment: have you tried clicking next ?

Comment: Android SDK in not the same as JDK. Please click next and install Android SDK

Comment: you need to install JAVA also from https://java.com/en/download/ and add it to your system path also

Comment: + This window is starting android studio.  First screen.

Comment: I already installed jdk. (9.0.4)

Comment: install [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an Android SDK installed in your system, because JDK and SDK are different things, even it's not necessary to install JDK as Android Studio ships with embedded JDK itself.
Just click next, It'll download the SDK itself, If you're sure you've the SDK, then just point to the Path of it.